# How to use Samsung TV Camera VG-STC5000 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, samsung, camera, uvc

I would like to use my Samsung TV Camera VG-STC5000 on Ubuntu 20.04.

When I connect it I get these logs:

```
[  673.032078] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  673.183403] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=2065, bcdDevice= 9.02
[  673.183406] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  673.183407] usb 1-4: Product: USB2.0 UVC HQ WebCam
[  673.183408] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Alpha Imaging Tech. Corp.
[  673.206482] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device USB2.0 UVC HQ WebCam (04e8:2065)
[  673.206655] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 2 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  673.207400] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 3 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  673.208784] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  673.209401] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 11 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  673.210150] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 13 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 1).
[  673.214900] uvcvideo: Failed to query (GET_INFO) UVC control 4 on unit 3: -32 (exp. 1).
[  673.218487] input: USB2.0 UVC HQ WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:08.0/0000:06:00.1/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input20
```

This is lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04e8:2065 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd USB2.0 UVC HQ WebCam
```

In Cheese it is displayed as a camera "Device" but it does not work at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Samsung did not produce drivers for this product, at least for Windows, MacOS, or Linux, and there doesn't appear to be any generic driver support under Linux for this device.

I bought this device in 2014 for use with Skype on a Samsung TV, and after Microsoft discontinued the Skype app on Smart TVs, this webcam became a paperweight for me as well.

Someone has begun trying to compile a driver for Windows (see here: https://github.com/Psypher9/VG-STC-Driver), but the last update to the repository was in July 2018, and the "Issues" section indicates that the driver is not in working order, or under active development for that matter.